# Selenium WebDriver Apache POI(unable to read numeric value from excel)

Tags: java, eclipse, excel

I am trying to export data Excel to Web pages using Apache POI. I have been able to export the numeric data(i.e. 123) to excel, but all of the values are being exported as Float(i.e. 123.0), I need them to keep their data type i.e numeric

```
            FileInputStream fi = new      FileInputStream("C:\\eclipse\\eclipse\\example\\DRRT.xls");

           HSSFWorkbook eb = new HSSFWorkbook(fi);

           HSSFSheet sh = eb.getSheet("Sheet1");

           HSSFRow row=null;

           HSSFCell cell = null;

           HSSFCell cell1 =null;

           for(int i=1;i<=sh.getLastRowNum();i++)

           {

           row =  sh.getRow(i);

           cell = row.getCell(0);

           cell1 = row.getCell(1);

           System.out.println(i +"   login ");

           System.out.println(cell +"   "+cell1);

           String s = cell.getStringCellValue(); // for user name

           String s1 = String.valueOf(cell1);    // for password

           WebDriver we = new FirefoxDriver();

           we.get("https;//……………");

           we.findElement(By.name("txtUsername")).sendKeys(s);

           we.findElement(By.name("txtPassword")).sendKeys(s1);

           we.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();

           System.out.println(we.getTitle());

           Thread.sleep(3000);

           we.findElement(By.partialLinkText("LOGOUT")).click();

           we.close();

           }
```

I'm using user name : superuser
          password  : 123

But while running this script the numeric value gets converted into float, and i'm unable to logged in. sir, kindly help me to read the exact format of the cell value from excel sheet, so that i can pass it in the text field of the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covert password string to double and then cast to integer.

```
String s1 = String.valueOf(cell1);    // for password
s1 =(int)Double.parseDouble(s1) + "";
```

or if you make it just one row:

```
String s1 = (int) Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(cell1)) + "";
```

This will give you integer ouput as string "123".